# Media queries not getting applied to any screen size

Tags: css

I'm trying to create mobile first approach media queries. But in chrome dev screen simulator, I notice that the background color `red` shows up for all the screen size.

```
body{
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width:576px) {
  body{
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0;
  } 
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  body{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
  }  
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  body{
    background-color: pink;
    margin: 0;
  }  
 }

 @media (min-width:1200px) {
  body{
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Works just fine in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6usytztt/ Is this the only code you have? Or is there something else that may be interfering?

Comment: Try this line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` and check properly if your css is loaded, This works fine for me, one more thing a lot of phones have a screen width smaller than 768px so in chrome dev screen simulator keep your eye at the top of the screen see how the width changes.